# XSLT: filter and apply conditional logic while grouping/sorting

Tags: xslt

For input XML like:

```
<FlightOptions>
  <item>
     <Fares>
       <item>
         <FareClass>A</FareClass>
         <Fare>100</Fare>
         <FareType>E</FareType>
         <Seats>5</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>B</FareClass>
         <Fare>200</Fare>
         <FareType>E</FareType>
         <Seats>10</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>C</FareClass>
         <Fare>250</Fare>
         <FareType>E</FareType>
         <Seats>20</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>N</FareClass>
         <Fare>100</Fare>
         <FareType>F</FareType>
         <Seats>5</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>M</FareClass>
         <Fare>200</Fare>
         <FareType>F</FareType>
         <Seats>50</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>O</FareClass>
         <Fare>300</Fare>
         <FareType>F</FareType>
         <Seats>20</Seats>
       </item>
     </Fares>
     <Flight>
         <FlightNumber>YY232</FlightNumber>
         <Origin>JFK</Origin>
         <Destination>LHR</Destination>
         <DepTime>1300</DepTime>
         <ArrTime>2000</ArrTime>
     </Flight>
    </item>
</FlightOptions>
```

For the above XML, I need to preserve only a few Fares/item nodes where I first group by FareType (E and F) and keep the items starting from the cheapest Fare, but stopping if the Seats is >= 9. Eg., since A has only 5 seats, I need to pick the next highest fare B, but not C. Also, if Seats >= 9, I need to cap it to 9.

I am able to do the group and sort, but unable to walk the fares and apply the logic to pick the fares as long as Seats <= 9 for that FareType. The other complication is that the output XML must reorder the Fares/items such that FareType E nodes come first in descending order of Fare, followed by N node (if present in the source), and then the other FareType F nodes in descending order of Fare.

Output XML would be:

```
<FlightOptions>
  <item>
     <Fares>
       <item>
         <FareClass>B</FareClass>
         <Fare>200</Fare>
         <FareType>E</FareType>
         <Seats>9</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>A</FareClass>
         <Fare>100</Fare>
         <FareType>E</FareType>
         <Seats>5</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>N</FareClass>
         <Fare>100</Fare>
         <FareType>F</FareType>
         <Seats>5</Seats>
       </item>
       <item>
         <FareClass>M</FareClass>
         <Fare>200</Fare>
         <FareType>F</FareType>
         <Seats>9</Seats>
       </item>
     </Fares>
     <Flight>
         <FlightNumber>YY232</FlightNumber>
         <Origin>JFK</Origin>
         <Destination>LHR</Destination>
         <DepTime>1300</Deptime>
         <ArrTime>2000</ArrTime>
     </Flight>
    </item>
<FlightOptions>
```

Have been trying to readup on Muenchian grouping examples but I am having trouble understanding how to apply along with an identity transform (since I have to keep the Flight structure along with the Fares/item nodes).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused about some of your requirements. You should paste the exact output you're expecting for the XML above.

Comment: What do you mean by "cheapest fare"? I don't see any price information. Please, explain. An example of the wanted output (for the given XML document) together with explanation why exactly this output is produced, would be great.

Comment: The <Fare> item is the price of the airline seat. So this would be treated as a number sort.  The output XML would be a copy of the input XML I posted, except that the additional Fares/item nodes would be removed, keeping only the Fares that met the criteria, and keep the Flight node intact for that overall item

Comment: Apologies for not being clear - this is my first time posting to stackoverflow, so I was struggling with the XML formatting. I've now updated the original post with the desired output XML. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you post the XSLT you are currently using, as that would help too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get away with not using grouping in this instance, as really all you are doing are sorting, and just excluding some elements.

So, when matching the **Fares** element, you sort the **item** elements, like so

```
     <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
        <xsl:sort select="FareType"/>
        <xsl:sort select="Fare"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Next, when you match each such **item** element, you can just test for whether any previous element with the same **FareType** is already greater than 9. If there are no such nodes, then because you have sorted by Fare, you know to include the node.

```
<xsl:template match="Fares/item">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::item[FareType=current()/FareType][Seats > 9])">
       <!-- copy node -->
    </xsl:if>
```

Here is the full XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="Fares">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
            <xsl:sort select="FareType"/>
            <xsl:sort select="Fare"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Fares/item">
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::item[FareType=current()/FareType][Seats > 9])">
         <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Seats[. > 9]">
      <xsl:copy>9</xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<FlightOptions>
   <item>
      <Fares>
         <item>
            <FareClass>A</FareClass>
            <Fare>100</Fare>
            <FareType>E</FareType>
            <Seats>5</Seats>
         </item>
         <item>
            <FareClass>B</FareClass>
            <Fare>200</Fare>
            <FareType>E</FareType>
            <Seats>9</Seats>
         </item>
         <item>
            <FareClass>N</FareClass>
            <Fare>100</Fare>
            <FareType>F</FareType>
            <Seats>5</Seats>
         </item>
         <item>
            <FareClass>M</FareClass>
            <Fare>200</Fare>
            <FareType>F</FareType>
            <Seats>9</Seats>
         </item>
      </Fares>
      <Flight>
         <FlightNumber>YY232</FlightNumber>
         <Origin>JFK</Origin>
         <Destination>LHR</Destination>
         <DepTime>1300</DepTime>
         <ArrTime>2000</ArrTime>
      </Flight>
   </item>
</FlightOptions>
```

Do also note the template match for **Seats** to limit then to 9.

Comment: Tim - sorry for the delay in getting back - this was absolutely a life saver! My understanding and deep appreciation for XSLT and moreso the guru's who practice it has grown manifold! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Tim C - your answer worked fabulously all this while. Now we have a small enhancement, and i'm trying to figure out the right way. Using the same XML/XSL info in this question, what we need now is to sequentially replace the "FareClass" letter with A,B,C... except the FareClass letters G and Y which should be preserved. I've seen stackoverflow question #7011714 - but not able to determine how to call it.

Comment: Hello! As this question is a year old, the best thing to do would be to ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Sure Tim - appreciate your prompt response! I'll repost the XML and XSLT right away

Comment: Hello Tim C - have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924600/replace-xml-values-with-sequential-alphabets-in-xsl-transform