# XSLT 2.0 - Removing an attribute while sorting with grouping

Tags: xslt

how could I remove an attribute from tags while I'm sorting and grouping them?

I found [how to apply conditional logic while sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074924/xslt-filter-and-apply-conditional-logic-while-grouping-sorting), but not how to combine it with grouping.

My code actually looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|IL|CL|BL|INST|CDOL|TL|SL|GL|DL|'" />
<xsl:template match="taskDesc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="sectionDesc" group-adjacent="replace(@name, '^(.*)?_[^_]*$', '$1')">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder,
                                concat('|', replace(@name, '^.*?_([^_]*$)', '$1'), '|')))"
        data-type="number" />
    </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <-- Copy
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's an attribute for some `sectionDesc` tags called `FMOrder` that I need to remove.
This attribute is used in others tags outside `taskDesc`, so I can't remove it globally.

Input file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FEFExchangeFile>
    <!-- Tons of tags -->
    <logicConf>
        <resource> <!-- Tons of attrs -->
            <taskDesc> <!-- Tons of attrs -->
                <sectionDesc name="a_b_c_GL" otherstuff="dummy" FMOrder="someothervalue"></sectionDesc>
                <sectionDesc name="a_b_c_IL" otherstuff="dummy" FMOrder="somevalue"></sectionDesc>
                <!-- Many other tags like this with or without FMOrder attr -->
            </taskDesc>
        </resource>
    </logicConf>
</FEFExchangeFile>
```

Comment: Francesco, please edit your questions to show us a sample of the XML input and of the corresponding result you want. Is the XSLT you have shown complete?

Comment: Sorry, I will able to show you a part of the XML input tomorrow, I thought it wasn't necessary. The XSLT is complete, it's just a sorting with an attribute removal.

Comment: If you want to remove an attribute node on a certain element then using a template `<xsl:template match="sectionDesc/@FMOrder"/>` does that, as long as nodes are processed by templates. Currently your grouping and sorting does not further pass on the nodes for processing, I posted http://stackoverflow.com/a/16797326/252228, maybe it helps and suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see your XML but perhaps changing

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="sectionDesc" group-adjacent="replace(@name, '^(.*)?_[^_]*$', '$1')">
<xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder,
                            concat('|', replace(@name, '^.*?_([^_]*$)', '$1'), '|')))"
    data-type="number" />
</xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="sectionDesc" group-adjacent="replace(@name, '^(.*)?_[^_]*$', '$1')">
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder,
                            concat('|', replace(@name, '^.*?_([^_]*$)', '$1'), '|')))"
    data-type="number" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

and adding a template

```
<xsl:template match="sectionDesc/@FMOrder"/>
```

helps.

Comment: I added my input code and it works with your suggestion. Thank you.